# Пауза при выполнении цикла

Tags: xcode, циклы, iphone, objective-c

Доброго времени суток. прошу подсказать.
Есть цикл:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

......... тут некие действия производятся с i-той переменной

(тут должны быть некие действия для паузы в 2 сек)

}
```

как сделать что после прохождения каждой итерации цикла, после выполнения всех действий была пауза например 2 сек?
Т.е. например там в каждом прохождении меняются картинки, дак вот когда сменилась первая - пауза 2 сек, далее второе прохождение - сменилась вторая картинка и опять пауза и т.д.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть несколько вариантов:

1. Использовать функции типа

   - [`sleep(unsigned int seconds)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/sleep.3.html)  (`usleep()`)
   - `[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval: seconds]`

Но это не самый лучший вариант, поскольку будет блокироваться главный поток (`thread`) программы, что будет выглядеть как «зависание» для пользователя.

1. При помощи `NSTimer` назначить выполнение необходимых действий с определённым интервалом:

   ```
    static int kCycles = 5;

    - (void)scheduleAction
    {
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1.0 // Раз в секунду
                                         target: self
                                       selector: @(doSmth:)
                                       userInfo: NULL
                                       repeats:  YES]; // Действие повторяющееся 
    }

    - (void)doSmth: (NSTimer *)timer
    {
       static int count = 0;
       // ...
       // Делаем дела
       // ...
       if (++count == kCycles) {
           // Как только действие повторилось
           // 5 раз — уничтожаем таймер
           [timer invalidate];
           timer = nil;
       }
    }
   ```

   *P.S. В примере выше таймер будет создан в текущей [runloop](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html). Разумеется, можно создать таймер вручную и добавить его в любую runloop по вашему выбору.*

Comment: Спасибо, суть понятна.

Answer (score 0):

Еще есть метод вызова селектора через определенный промежуток времени:

```
performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:
```

Что касается задачи я бы заюзал NSOperationQueue